# p-calendar hide under container panel on bs-modal in angular 7

Tags: bootstrap-modal, angular7, primeng

I have used primeNg  component on bootstrap's bs-modal,i used scrollbar for multiple notes. when click on p-calendar component, calendar is hiding behind scroll bar. As per showing in image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following dependacnies

> 1. HostListener from angular-core
> 2. import $ from 'jquery';

and write following code to your ts component file.

```
     @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
     openCloseCalendar(ev) {    
       if("P-CALENDAR" == ev.path[2].tagName || ev.path[3].tagName){
          let calElem = ev.path[2] || ev.path[3];
          let target = $(calElem).find(".ui-datepicker")[0];
          let calTop = $($(calElem).find("input")[0]).offset();
          if(calTop && calTop.top){
            $(target).css({"display":"block", "min-width": "200px", "position": "fixed", "top": calTop.top, left: ev.offsetY})
          }   
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `[appendTo]: 'body'` in your p-calendar.